# Actions undertaken in QGIS somewhere stored as Python code in a history file?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

For practioners that are not willing to study all the methods for each class, it would be helpful if every action that was made within the QGIS interface can be looked up afterwards in a history file with the according python code. In ArcGIS something like that exists. Is it available in QGIS as well?

Answer (score 2):

Something like that exists only for the QGIS Processing Toolbox where you can look up the history/log in the corresponding menu entry.

All other interactions are afaik not logged.